# How do I change the "Searching for somethings" text?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

When I dispatch an action, like getQuiz, Bixby will show "Searching for Quizs" before it finds the quiz. How do I customize this text?

Answer (score 2):

Use a [progress dialog](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/ref-topics/dialog-modes.dialog-events#progress-event) e.g. do something like this:

```
dialog (Progress) {
  match: viv.weather.SolarNoon {
    from-output: viv.weather.GetSolarNoon (this)
  }
  choose (Random) {
    template (Performing solar calculations...)
    template (Consulting my analemma...)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have any progress dialogs, you can use the `type (Calculation)` for the action.